# Панорамирование и зумирование холста с UIElement'ами

Tags: c#, wpf, zoom, панорамы

## Описание задачи

Есть холст на котором в процессе работы можно добавлять/создавать и располагать контролы, например Label. Нужно сделать так, чтобы все содержимое можно было панорамировать и зумировать мышью (так как все просто не поместится). Наподобие того, как это реализовано в **графическом редакторе Picasa**.

## Реализация сейчас

Долго гуглил и читал про возможности WPF, нашел реализацию контейнера с околонужным функционалом и немного изменил под свои нужды, хотя реализация очень мне не нравится. Вот код:

MyCanvas.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace FTree.UI
{
    public class MyCanvas : Canvas
    {
        private List<UIElement> elements = new List<UIElement>();
        private ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
        private TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
        private TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        private Point origin;
        private Point start;

        private TranslateTransform GetTranslateTransform(UIElement element)
        {
            return (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)element.RenderTransform)
              .Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        }

        private ScaleTransform GetScaleTransform(UIElement element)
        {
            return (ScaleTransform)((TransformGroup)element.RenderTransform)
              .Children.First(tr => tr is ScaleTransform);
        }
        

        public MyCanvas()
        {
            group.Children.Add(st);
            group.Children.Add(tt);

            this.MouseWheel += child_MouseWheel;
            this.MouseLeftButtonDown += child_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.MouseLeftButtonUp += child_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            this.MouseMove += child_MouseMove;
            this.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(
              child_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown);
        }

        public void Add(UIElement element)
        {
            element.RenderTransform = group;

            elements.Add(element);
            this.Children.Add(element);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            foreach(var i in elements)
            {
                // reset zoom
                var st = GetScaleTransform(i);
                st.ScaleX = 1.0;
                st.ScaleY = 1.0;

                // reset pan
                var tt = GetTranslateTransform(i);
                tt.X = 0.0;
                tt.Y = 0.0;
            }
        }

        #region Child Events

        private void child_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var i in elements)
            {
                var st = GetScaleTransform(i);
                var tt = GetTranslateTransform(i);

                double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
                if (!(e.Delta > 0) && (st.ScaleX < .3 || st.ScaleY < .3))
                    return;

                Point relative = e.GetPosition(i);
                double absoluteX;
                double absoluteY;

                absoluteX = relative.X * st.ScaleX + tt.X;
                absoluteY = relative.Y * st.ScaleY + tt.Y;

                st.ScaleX += zoom;
                st.ScaleY += zoom;

                tt.X = absoluteX - relative.X * st.ScaleX;
                tt.Y = absoluteY - relative.Y * st.ScaleY;
            }
        }

        private void child_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if(elements.Count != 0)
            {
                var i = elements[0];
                var tt = GetTranslateTransform(i);
                start = e.GetPosition(this);
                origin = new Point(tt.X, tt.Y);
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                i.CaptureMouse();
            }
        }

        private void child_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (elements.Count != 0)
            {
                var i = elements[0];
                i.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }

        void child_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Reset();
        }

        private void child_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                foreach (var i in elements)
                {
                    var tt = GetTranslateTransform(i);
                    Vector v = start - e.GetPosition(this);
                    tt.X = origin.X - v.X;
                    tt.Y = origin.Y - v.Y;
                }
            }
            
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FTree.UI
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle();
            rec1.Height = 100;
            rec1.Width = 100;
            rec1.Fill = Brushes.Orange;


            myCanvas.Add(rec1);
            MyCanvas.SetLeft(rec1, 200);
            MyCanvas.SetTop(rec1, 200);

            Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle();
            rec2.Height = 100;
            rec2.Width = 100;
            rec2.Fill = Brushes.Orange;

            myCanvas.Add(rec2);

            MyCanvas.SetLeft(rec2, 50);
            MyCanvas.SetTop(rec2, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Проблема

Проблема в реализации зумировании (объекты слишком растекаются, наезжают друг на друга), а также в том, что применение подобных махинаций я решил сделать через обращение к списку элементов (думаю есть другой лучший способ). Еще раз напомню, что я ориентируюсь я то, как реализовано панорамирование и зумирование в **Picasa**. Видел реализации зума картинки - похожее хотелось бы сделать со множеством элементов на холсте. В каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Долго гуглили, читали, но про MVVM не слышали, а так же не заметили существование `ViewPort`. Это подсказки. Первая вам даст возможность выжить и полюбить WPF, вторая как раз чтобы приблизить и отдалить, а так же перемещаться по источнику изображения. Есть еще 2 подсказки - `Thumb` и `Adorner`, но сначала хотя-бы с первой разберитесь. Вообще для WPF ваша задача не сложная, но вы уже ушли не в те дебри.

Comment: Еще не пишите свой код в конструкторе окна, для начала используйте обработчик события `Window.Loaded` вместо этого.

Comment: @aepot Уточню, что мой холст, на котором располагаются объекты должен быть как бы бесконечным, поэтому такие примеры как: [это](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97871/WPF-simple-zoom-and-drag-support-in-a-ScrollViewer) не подойдут. Я пробовал ZoomBorder [здесь](https://qastack.ru/programming/741956/pan-zoom-image), думал установить там контейнер компановки в котором будут создаваться объекты, но как то не выходит. И в итоге пришел к тому, что в вопросе, но оно плохо зумирует. 
Говоря о ViewPort вы имели в виду [это](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Han.Wpf.ViewportControl/1.0.0) или VP3D?

Comment: В таком случае вам ни Canvas, не наследование от него, не подойдут, потому что канвас не бесконечен. ViewPort я имел в виду [Viewbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.viewbox?view=net-5.0), просто опечатался, простите.

Comment: @aepot ViewBox то я пробовал, он может иметь один дочерний элемент, но так как создается множество объектов, я думал запихнуть туда контейнер, по типу как предлагают [здесь](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level12/12_4.php), но применяя выше написанный код получается, что двигать буду компоновщик, да еще и почему то объекты внутнри canvas за рамки ViewBox выходят при перемещении, меню закрывают. Короче, это плохо работает. Когда объект 1 работает все идеально.

Comment: Контейнером может быть совершенно любая панель, хоть `Grid`.

Comment: @aepot Представим, что у меня есть бесконечная плоскость, на которой расположены объекты, а в будущем можно будет создать объекты в любом месте этой плоскости. Вот я пытаюсь теперь сделать на ней панорамирование и масштабирование. В вопросе плохо работает зум, а если делать canvas внутри viewbox, то там будет плохо работать панорамирование.

Comment: @aepot я понимаю, что любая панель, но на Gride не создашь объект в той точке, где это нужно (ну где допустим курсор сейчас), или я ошибаюсь? По этой причине я выбирал Canvas.

Comment: Вы же можете на гриде воткнуть кнопку, установив ей левый и верхний марджин руками? Значит и програмно можно.

Comment: @aepot Установка компановщика Grid в ViewBox проблему не решает. Да, масштабирование работает хорошо, но Grid то тоже не бесконечен. По факту мы двигаем компоновщик и визуально это видно, хотя в действительности нужно чтобы ощущалось не движение компоновщика, а движение всех элеметов внутри компоновщика, подобно тому как это работает в коде вопроса (панорамирование). Но масштабирование там плохо работает. К тому же при транспонировании грида он залезает например на меню, которое видно на скриншотах.